# Exception in (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException)

Tags: attributes, magento2.2

After changing production mode to developer mode.

This error came

```
    Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 925

#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/opt/lampp/htdo...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(509): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(467): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getElementAttribute('body', 'class')
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/app/code/Sm/ShopBy/Controller/Category/View.php(205): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->addBodyClass('page-products')
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/generated/code/Sm/ShopBy/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php(24): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View->execute()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->execute()
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/generated/code/Sm/ShopBy/Controller/Category/View/Interceptor.php(39): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Sm\ShopBy\Controller\Category\View\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#30 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#32 /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#33 {main}
```

I'm using magento 2.2.

Comment: This seems to be a xml syntax error... Check in your custom module config or system xml file in which you have used **Class** attribute by mistake

Comment: Where i can find system.xml? It is located in too many folders.

Comment: check your custom module in which you have worked